# Installing Neovim 0.7 on Ubuntu?

Tags: neovim, linux-ubuntu

I just moved from Mac to Ubuntu.

I have set everything up but my lua keybindings are following the 0.7 configurations.

When I install neovim on Ubuntu it gives me 0.6.

I tried this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neovim-ppa/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install neovim
```

But it still gives me 0.6.

How do I target the 0.7 installation on Ubuntu?

Comment: [This page linked from the NeoVim readme](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=neovim) doesn't yet list 0.7. You might want to try a source build.

Comment: mmm I see. 

Just curious why I was able to update to 0.7.0 with Brew on mac? are they separate repos?

Comment: Completely; brew is a package manager for mac (that happens to have a linux counter part, linuxbrew). They maintain separate "package definitions."

Comment: Understood. I guess the solution is to re map my keybindings back to the 0.6 version. Thanks Ben

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I think you can write your comment as an answer here, since the question seems to be answered or am I wrong?

Comment: @TornaxO7 I'll add the answer, but it will fall out of date if/when Ubuntu gets 0.7 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page linked from the NeoVim readme](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=neovim) doesn't yet list 0.7. You might want to try a source build.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neovim-ppa/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install neovim
```

[From the "Installing NeoVim" wiki page](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim)

I was struggling with nvim0.4 but those commands did the work to install nvim0.7
on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use the "traditional" Linux way and

1. install homebrew: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
2. `brew install neovim`

Comment: I wouldn't call this the "traditional" Linux way (which would be compile from source or use your distro's package manager), but this is definitely viable.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned which version/release of Ubuntu you are using.

You can find the [deb](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/v0.7.0/nvim-linux64.deb) of neovim-0.7 from the [neovim release](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases) page.

I am using it on my debian testing without any issues so far.

Comment: issue has already been solved. See the answer. 

Also, it was a month ago so its probably different now

Comment: I did see the answer. I just pointed out the location to a deb which could be installed easily without resorting ppa's. This *maybe* be useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Change `stable` to `unstable`:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neovim-ppa/unstable`

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) Thanks to your contribution. Your answer is very compact. Maybe could you elaborate and repeat part of the solution drafted on the question to have a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I haven't yet committed to Neovim, I'm playing with [the appimage](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/v0.7.0/nvim.appimage). You can't get an easier (un) install procedure than with those.

If you're unfamiliar with appimages, just:

- Download the file
- Put it where you want it
- Make it executable
- run it

If I ever decide to switch from vim to nvim, I might switch to compiling it from source, but right now I'm not convinced.